# What is the best way to send large amount of strings to stdout?

Tags: c, char, stdout

I have a function that returns pointer to char which contains 4 characters.

```c
char *foo(unsigned short n)
{
    return "abc\n";
}
```

Now I run it 100 000 times and I send results to stdout. And it has to be done the fastest way possible.
Running this function 100 000 times without writing takes about 0.45s.
What I've tried:

- printf

```c
    ... 
    printf("%s", foo(n));
    ...
```

`~6.5s`

- fwrite

```c
    ...
    fwrite(foo(n), 4, 1, stdout); 
    ...
```

`~9.9s`

- strncat to buffer and fwrite

```c
    char buffer[400001] = "";
    ... 
    strncat(buffer, foo(n), 4);
    ... 
    fwrite(buffer, 400000, 1, stdout);
```

`~7s`

Is there a way to make it faster? I would like to go at least below 5s.

Comment: You forget puts() (per line) or a cycle with puch()...

Comment: If you time your program, you might find it *actually* uses only a few milliseconds of CPU time. The rest is all due to how fast your output terminal can process the text. .. Why do you need to print so much data to the screen? You cannot read that fast, can you?

Comment: I don't believe those numbers. Run it as `./a.out > /tmp/out.txt` to get a more realistic measure (or even redirect to `/dev/null` first).

Comment: And definitely `fputs` rather than `fprintf` if you only have a fixed string.

Comment: As alternative you may even check unbuffered I/O (just in case)

Comment: Why negative vote? "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" I don't think any of those statements is true.

Comment: I don't see how it's "useful".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is useful for everyone who is as dumb as me to output large amounts of data to console.

Comment: You can even go a little faster by using `write (1, buffer, 4);` . `printf()`, `puts()`, etc, use `write()` at the end.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix Strange thing but `write` is about 0.30s slower than `fputs` which is almost not measurable.

Comment: Strange indeed. If you are developing it using Linux, can you `strace` it? That will reveal to you what the program uses to actually write to the console. `fputs()` should eventually call `write()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your kind comments I did some more testing and what I came with is that `fputs()`is the fastest. Being ~0.45s for  `> out.txt` and ~0.61s for `> NUL`. So it turns out that console output was slowing everything.